# ChronicleMap is causing high heap usage / OOM error

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-map

My understanding of ChronicleMaps is that they store data off heap, and if specified, using the disk with off-heap memory used to map to where on the disk the data is stored. Is this correct? I have an application running with a ChronicleMap that's experiencing higher heap usage and getting OOM errors. What am I not understanding correctly about using a ChronicleMap?

Comment: You may be better off posting an issue on the project's GitHub. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map

Comment: Asked there and my issue was closed